# Error when install python package. Why i got this error?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, installation, statsmodels, python-packaging

I got an error when I installed the scikit-learn and statsmodels packages using pip.

First I successfully installed numpy, pandas, scipy, and matplotlib. But after that, when I tried to install scikit-learn and statsmodels it showed the following output error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\riyanto widodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Riyanto Widodo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcqcobil\statsmodels\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Riyanto Widodo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcqcobil\statsmodels\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Riyanto Widodo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-srum5sfl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have to use Python 3.8? I also encountered some problems with my favourite data science libraries and went back to 3.7. I guess it's a matter of time before everything works with the new version.

Comment: i see. i ever installed them in 3.7 version on august. and it worked well, no error. today i reinstall my windows and install new python. thanks for your respond sir. God bless your brain